# why my return function is not working python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, return-value

```
initialValues = input('Please enter a space separated set of values for y, h and g(0): ')

values = []
values.append(initialValues)

theValues = []

for item in values:
    item = item.split(' ')
    for index in range(len(item)):
        item[index] = int(item[index])
    theValues.append(item)

y = theValues[0][0]
h = theValues[0][1]
g0 = theValues[0][2]

def Sumrecur(y,h,g0):
    if y == 0 :
        return g0
    else:
        sum = 0
        for k in range(1,y):
            sum = sum + Sumrecur(k,h,g0)*h
    return sum

Sumrecur(y,h,g0)
```

this is a function i'm currently working on. I'm confused as the return sum command doesn't work. Is there anything wrong with the code?? Sorry it might sound silly to some of you but I really don't know how to fix this.
thanks before!

Comment: Doesnt work ? Are you getting any error messages ?

Comment: Could you give an example of input data and expected output?

Comment: i've edited the post for the inputt. and like the expected output would just the sum of the recursion functionn. @PierPaolo

Comment: i didn't get any error messages also on the python shell. (>>>) i just get that instead. @Abhimanyusingh

Comment: Although thats not the question , But you are doing way too much work for getting the input . Using `y,h,g0 = map(int,raw_input('INPUT ').split(' '))` should suffice .

Answer (score 1):

Once you've gone 1 recursion deep you need to return multiple times to actually return the value. Basically you've returned the value to the last recursion but this isn't the original one you called so there will be no output. Maybe write to a global variable or print the value instead.

Comment: thank you for answering my question!! but i still don't quite understand, can yoh give me an example???

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR : 
I would try using `range(0,y)` in your for loop.

BREAKDOWN:
Your recursion depends on the value of `y` and only ends whenever `y` equals 0 .

Lets see how the recursions are called using an example

STEP 1
`Sumrecur(3,1,1)` will call `Sumrecur(1,1,1)` and `Sumrecur(2,1,1)`

STEP 2a :
`Sumrecur(1,1,1)` calls nothing

STEP 2b : 
`Sumrecur(2,1,1)` calls `Sumrecur(1,1,1)`

STEP 3:
`Sumrecur(1,1,1)` calls nothing

You see what the issue is ? The value of y never equals 0 , so it never enters the

```
   if y == 0 :
      return g0
```

I would try using `range(0,y)` in your `for` loop.

Comment: hello! first of all thank you so much for answering my questions!! howeverr, i also add return sum for the else condition, so i'm just wondering why it doesn't work. it doesn't return me anythingg. I've tried using range(0,y) but it also didnt work :'(

Comment: @RebeccaMaria Are you sure you are printing it ? . `Sumrecur(y,h,g0)` will just call the function . Since you are returning the value from the function you will have to use `print Sumrecur(y,h,g0)` .

Comment: @RebeccaMaria And am pretty sure you will always get 0 as return value if you use `range(1,y)` . You should try with range(0,y) to get some output .